# Rotations of a surface of revolution about its axis are diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently studying Differential Geometry using Manfredo's book.

In chapter 2, section 2, exercise 11, I am asked to prove that the rotations of a surface of revolution S about its axis are diffeomorphisms of S.

This one exercise has been particularly tough for me, as I didn't find an angle to solve it yet. My best approach was to use polar coordinates and apply a given rotation to it, but I was unsuccessful to formalize it.

Can anybody help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can suppose that the axis of revolution is $z$ and that the surface of revolution $S$ can be described by a Cartesian equation

$$f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z)$$

Now a rotation of angle $\theta$ about the $z$ axis is given by a matrix

$$r_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0& 0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Using the cartesian equation, it is clear that $r_\theta$ maps a point of $S$ onto another point of $S$.

As any rotation is bijective and smooth (as its inverse), we get the desired result.